# 'str' object has no attribute 'name' in discord.py issue

Tags: python, class, discord, discord.py

i am new to discord.py and i needed a way to store a lot variables in one it worked using the class function but the variable(p0.name, p0.car etc) doesnt print and it doesnt allow me to change the value.
i tried everything possible like changing the class name, making the class into a different variable and so on. I am new to discord.py and im still learning

```
import discord

import os
import random
import time

from discord.ext import commands

BMW330i = 'https://bringatrailer.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/2003_bmw_330i_zhp_15644247438495d565ef6IMG_2270-e1566433399592.jpg?fit=940%2C628'
HONDAs2000 = 'https://cimg3.ibsrv.net/cimg/www.s2ki.com/1600x900_85-1/343/1-Make-Improvements-408343.jpg'
NISSANsilvia ='https://static.carthrottle.com/workspace/uploads/posts/2015/12/9a8cd0a4a74fb73c29f564f6e33aa20f.jpg'

users = 0
p0 = '.'
p0name = '.'

class user:
    def __init__(self, name, car, car1,hp, hp1, carc, car1c, cari, car1i, money, daily):
        self.name = name
        self.car = car
        self.car1 = car1
        self.carc = carc
        self.car1c = car1c
        self.hp = hp
        self.hp1 = hp1
        self.money = money
        self.daily = daily
        self.cari = cari
        self.car1i = car1i

 YOU WANT IT TO BE.
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=";")

@bot.command()
async def test(message):
    await message.channel.send(p0name)

@bot.command()
async def reg(cxt):
    global users
    carstart = random.randint(1,3)
    if users == 0:
        await cxt.channel.send('Hey, ' + cxt.author.name)
        if carstart == 1:
            p0 = user(str(cxt.author.name), '2003 BMW 330i', 'Empty', (235), 'Empty', (9), 'Empty',  BMW330i, 'Empty', (1000), (0))
        if carstart == 2:
            p0 = user(str(cxt.author.name), '2000 Honda S2000', 'Empty', (240), 'Empty', (9), 'Empty',  HONDAs2000, 'Empty', (1000), (0))
        if carstart == 3:
            p0 = user(str(cxt.author.name),  '2000 Nissan Silvia', 'Empty', (243), 'Empty', (9), 'Empty',  NISSANsilvia, 'Empty', (1000), (0))
        await cxt.channel.send('Welcome to Brooklyn, ' + p0.name + ' lucky for you I managed to fetch a ' + p0.car + ' with ' + str(p0.hp) + 'HP')
        await cxt.channel.send(p0.cari)
        await cxt.channel.send(p0.name)
        users = users + 1
    else:
        await cxt.channel.send('You have to @ yourself')
        mention = ('<@' + str(cxt.author.id) + '>')
        await cxt.channel.send(mention)
        await cxt.channel.send(cxt.author.id)
# EXECUTES THE BOT WITH THE SPECIFIED TOKEN. TOKEN HAS BEEN REMOVED AND USED JUST AS AN EXAMPLE.
bot.run('ODAxODA0NjY0ODM2MDYzMjQy.YAmAyA.snnqa9lOqYheREA0_PqH3GxK94E')
```

this is the code that comes after

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\inaam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\inaam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\inaam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace `ctx.author.name` with `ctx.author`

Comment: a new error comes ```discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "Member") to str```

Comment: ```str(ctx.author)``` not ```user(str(ctx.author))```

Comment: i cant because i think that will discard the whole purpose of the user class

Comment: but it creates an entirely new object, you can still use just ```ctx.author``` to access its attributes

Comment: where exaclty should i change it?

Comment: If you mean the ```str(ctx.author)```, just use it when you are using it in print(), or whenever you want to concatenate it with a string

Comment: oh im sorry if i made a mistake in the question, but i was asking if i could print the class variables like p0.car, p0.hp etc.

Comment: im terribly sorry if i sound rude

Comment: ohhh, thats simple, if the class variable is not string, use ```str(<class variable in here with no greater than or less than signs>)``` if they arent, just type them as is them, if you want to put them in a string with some other variable use ```f''``` example: ```f'{<variable>} bla bla bla {<variable>}'``` and where there are ```{}```, it will show the value of the variable even if it's not string

Comment: i did and it still says the same thing again sorry for taking your time